# Mismatched same Server's Time using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to use my web server's date and time using `PHP` and `AJAX`. The problem is, `PHP` gives a different time and `AJAX` gives a different. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Below is my code.

**AJAX**

```
function srvTime() {
var xmlHttp;
try {
    //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (err1) {
    //IE
    try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    }
    catch (err2) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (eerr3) {
            //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
            alert("AJAX not supported");
        }
    }
}
xmlHttp.open('HEAD', window.location.href.toString(), false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
xmlHttp.send('');
return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}


document.write("Server Time and Date through AJAX: "+srvTime());


var phpDate = "<?php echo Date('d-m-Y H:i:s')?>"

document.write("Server Time and Date through PHP"+phpDate);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Server Time and Date through AJAX Mon, 09 Dec 2013 21:11:28 GMT //AJAX
Server Time and Date through PHP 09-12-2013 16:11:28 // PHP
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe other is GMT timezone and other GMT +- some amount? (different timezones)

Comment: i tested this code on the same server. I do not think there would be difference in GMT timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time
>   (GMT), without exception ([source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html))

Ajax response is in GMT format
And PHP Date returns server's time. You can check your server timezone using

```
date_default_timezone_get()
```

or checking "date.timezone" option in php.ini